# Index range scan vs index skip scan vs index fast full scan

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-administration

I have table

```
test_A(
    id1 number,
    id2 number,
    id3 number,
    name varchar2(10),
    create_dt date
)
```

I have two indexes one composite index `indx1` on `(id1,id2)` and  `indx2(id3)`. Now when I query this table `test_A` as

```sql
select * from test_A where id2=123 and 
create_dt=(select max(create_dt) from test_A where test_A.id2=id2);
```

I ran explain plan for this above SQL and it is using "index skip scan". If I create another index on `create_dt` then it using index fast full scan and over all cost and %cpu is showing higher than plan with Index skip scan. It is also using Index range scan after creating index on `create_dt`.

I could not come to conclusion which should be could? Do I need to create another Index on `create_dt` or is Index skip scan good? I believe Index skip is a feature of Oracle to run multiple index range scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to familiarize yourself with this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_optop.htm#CHDFJIJA
It is Oracle 12c related, however it is very usefull to gain understanding how oracle uses different index access pathes in all DBMS versions.

Your subquery is ambigous:

```
select max(create_dt) from test_A where test_A.id2=id2
```

both test_A.id2 and id2 references to the same test_A.id2, and the query is equivalent to this:

```
select * from test_A where id2=123 and 
create_dt=(select max(create_dt) from test_A where id2=id2);
```

or simply:

```
select * from test_A where id2=123 and 
create_dt=(select max(create_dt) from test_A where id2 is not null);
```

I suppose that you want something like this:

```
select * from test_A where id2=123 and 
create_dt=(select max(create_dt) 
           from test_A ALIAS 
           where test_A.id2=ALIAS.id2);
```

For the above query a composite index on id2+create_dt most likely give the best results, try it:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON test_A( id2, create_dt);
```

Comment: thanks for Above solution. I have created composite in index on those 2 columns which gave reduced cost in explain plan. I have one more question suppose i have unique constraint created on another table on (id1,id2) and do we need to have index created externally or does unique constraint take care of Index. I have read about this in many forums some saying it will take care of Index some syaing need to create Index , cannot come to conclusion on this. Please let me know if you have any info on this.

Comment: Just try it yourself. See this link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/180be/1 there are three indentic tables there, first one without the index, second one with the index created using `create index`, and third with `constraint .. unique` inside the table definition. Run attached queries, and click on `View execution plan` links and compare indyvidual explain plans to see wich of them use  the index.